# Sublime Text 2 Vintage: Leave insert mode on focus lost

Tags: sublime-text-2

I'm using [Vintage](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html) mode (Vi bindings) on Sublime Text 2.

When switching back to ST2, I regularly get bitten by still being in insert mode, resulting in me entering "jjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkk".

Is there a way to automatically leave insert mode and go back to command mode when the ST2 window loses focus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've never used Sublime Text 2, but it looks like it might have promise... not changing from my Vim though {Grin}

The following **SHOULD** work for you to turn off Insert Mode when you lose focus, name it "**stop_insert_on_focus_lost.py**" and place it somewhere in your plugins folder.

Hopefully it'll work, had to scan the API and some of their example plugins to get the format and commands.  (never seen ST2 before though... do I get points for grokking their API, Python & Vintage mode in a few minutes?)

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import os.path

class StopInsertOnFocusLost(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_deactivated(self, view):
        view.run_command('exit_insert_mode')
```

Comment: Wow, this actually works -- you are incredible. (I dropped it into `Packages/StopInsertOnFocusLost/`.) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: I just noticed: When adding this plugin it will cause your search and replace fields to change to normal mode, too. So you always have to press "i" to get into insert mode to insert your search term.

How can we fix this?

Comment: Umm, Use VIM?  Read the Sublime Macro Documentation? Not like there's a lot to it... 1 line of code, 4 lines of header. Of COURSE it's going to shift things out of insert mode... it called 'stop-insert-on-focus-lost'.  Maybe you could save the 'search & replace' field current modes to be restored on window focus return?  Easiest fix... don't switch to any other apps, thus not losing focus... yay! no mode changes for S&R fields. (Theoretical Question: What are 'search & replace fields'? Must be a clicky-mousy thing. {Shrug})  Enjoy! {Grin} (Why would you stay in insert mode?)

Comment: Example: I press [/] to open up the search bar. But now I have to press [I] first before I can insert my search term.

Answer (score 4):

The plugin above is great but suffers from an annoying bug, as mentioned in the other comments. When you switch to something like the find menu or the go to anything popup you will be in command/normal mode there. What's worse, commands won't work entirely correctly because many of the vintage mode commands won't run in popups, so you're in a worse of both worlds situation.

This version fixes that:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import os.path

class StopInsertOnFocusLost(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_deactivated(self, view):
        view.run_command('exit_insert_mode')

    def on_activated(self, view):
        if view.settings().get('is_widget') == True:
            view.run_command('enter_insert_mode')
```

Thanks to the original answer for the starting code!

Answer (score 1):

I also have this to offer:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import os.path

class StopInsertOnFocusLost(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_deactivated(self, view):
        if view.file_name() and not view.settings().get('command_mode'):
            view.run_command('exit_insert_mode')
```

Adapted from lornix's answer -- fixes some edge cases. Name it `stop_insert_on_focus_lost.py` and add it under `Packages`.